# Passing a pointer as a private data member into a member function in Main

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on a problem for school where I am summing the values stored in a linear linked list.

I've got a struct that defines the node. It has a data portion and a pointer for next.

I have a class that has the functions that work on the list in the public section, and a pointer called `head` in the private section.

I've implemented a recursive function in my implementation file to sum values.
 It takes a `node*` as its argument.

My question is, how do I pass that `head` pointer into the function in `main()` if it is a private data member?

I've successfully implemented this iteratively, so please assume that the list is instantiated successfully in `main()`. I just can't figure out how to pass a pointer into my function from there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) showing the actual code you are trying to use and explain what is not working in it for you.  If the function is not a member of the class that has the `head` pointer, it simply does not have access to the pointer. So either make the function be a member of the class, or else have the class expose public access to the pointer.  Making the function be a class member would be best. Also, since you already have a working iterative solution, why do you need a recursive solution?

Comment: Because that's part of the problem. Please read my entire question before answering. I only need to know how to pass a private data member that is a pointer into my function in Main. I don't need to fix the function. I think it's more of a fundamental question that does not require code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I did read the whole question, and I addressed it in my last comment. The current design you described will not work. Only the class has access to the `head` pointer, so only the class can call the function. `main()` cannot, as it does not have access to `head`. So either make the function be a member of the class, or else add public access to `head`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass it in. The class already owns it. If I may your class should look something like this:

```
class Foo {
    node* _head;
    node* _tail;
public:
    Foo() : _head(nullptr), _tail(nullptr) {}
    ~Foo() {
        while(_head != nullptr) {
            node* temp = _head;

            _head = _head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    void insert(const int arg) {
         if(_head = _nullptr) {
             _head = new node(arg);
             _tail = _head;
         } else {
             _tail->next = new node(arg);
             _tail = _tail->next;
         }
    }
    int sum() const {
        int total = 0;

        for(auto i = _head; i != nullptr; i = i->next) {
            total += i->val;
        }

        return total;
    }
};
```

Note that `sum` has no need for `_head` to be passed to it because `_head` is in fact already a member of the object that `sum` is a method of.